# Caldera Forms custom progress bar

Tags: wordpress

This is my first time using Caldera Forms and I couldn't find where to add html custom progress bars.I tried finding any documentation on it but couldn't.
 Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer, so you will get a suited answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . You can give us some more information, Caldera Forms is a Plugin of Wordpress? What progress bars do you want to add and where have you inserted the form? Do you have a link to the documentation, it could be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. There is an html field select it and the in below options you can add your custom html. Any error in that html will result in form not functioning properly. it might show that html or the result of the html even with the error.